# Automotive protection: TVS, thermistor, or both?

Tags: voltage-regulator, automotive, protection, circuit-protection

This is a follow up question regarding my previous [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518554/dc1601b-demo-board-input-line-caught-fire-during-use) where I was informed my issue was due to inrush current.

I have a [DC1601B-C](https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/evaluation-kit-manuals/dc1601bf.pdf) buck-boost converter outputting 12V and up to 20 Amps. It is hooked up in an automotive circuit that is powered on with a key switch. The key switch turns on power from a 12V lead acid battery. There is also an alternator to charge the battery. I have a [SLD8S17A](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_TVS_Diode_SLD8S_Datasheet.pdf-1022642.pdf) TVS diode as protection on the input line for automotive load dump.

The regulator is supposed to be able to output up to 20A, and under my normal conditions I am running it at about 11 amps with various sensors, single board computers, and an ethernet hub. I can't go into specifics on the exact devices.

At the time of the board catching fire (as described in the post linked above) it was only powering the ethernet hub and a few of the sensors and should have only been outputting 2.25 amps maximum (could have been much less). The board was working fine, then the switch was keyed off, then back on, and that's when the fire happened.

To protect against inrush current I was thinking I would add a fuse leading to an NTC thermistor. Would this be a good solution? Should it go before or after the TVS diode? Would the thermistor work if the device was only briefly unpowered? In my research I can't seem to find a schematic of a thermistor being used with a TVS diode.

Another question is does my TVS diode need a resistor or capacitor (and what value)? I only have the TVS diode, but after some reading I have seen that some designs include a resistor before the diode to limit current.

Comment: Can you not define you output load parameters real/reactive , voltage and power?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 apologies, I have updated the post to contain more information and clarify some other details.

Comment: What output voltages?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Its a 12V output, I will add that in as well

Comment: No define the power load transient for 20A. These current drops can boost V overshoot when a lot of energy is stored.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I am not sure how to define that, unless you mean the graphs on page 6 of the regulator's datasheet I linked it shows an approximately 100mV dip when 10A is turned on and 100mV spike when 10A is switched off. If you are talking about for the battery, I'm not sure what that would be, but it is just a usual 12V lead acid battery. I would be surprised if the issue was voltage overshoot since I have a TVS diode that seemed unharmed and still functional after the fire. More what I'm worried about is some sort of inrush current.

Comment: Fire comes from heat which comes from excess resistance and high current surge. Find the resistance problem and fix it.

Comment: My question is more related to what protection circuitry I should use to block the inrush current, and what order the protection circuitry should be connected before my regulator.

Comment: Boost converters are notorious surge starters without a soft start signal or limiter.